# Trying to build query to get number of rows between two months using Knex.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, knex.js

I have an issue tracking management program where I am trying to build a SQL query to return an array of rows for each month.

I have tried using a while loop to loop through and push the length of rows after each one. However, it returns the array before the loop is done.

I know I could also use count() to get row length but I just need to get the months between 1-6;

Is there an easier query to use?

```
getMonthlyData(db, teamId){
    let monthlyData = [];
    let i = 1;
while (i < 6){
db
    .from('issues')
    .select('*')
    .where({team_id: teamId})
    .andWhereRaw(`EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_created::date) = ?`, [i])
    .then(rows => {
        console.log('Monthly data')
        console.log(rows);
        monthlyData.push(rows.length)
     })
     .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
     }) 
    }
    return monthlyData;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: So you want to have issues of months 1-6 of all of the years? Also you might need to convert date_created to some local time zone depending on issue tracker's time zone. Unless date_created is actually stored as local time instead of UTC.

Comment: Also the code seems to have a bug that variable `i` is never incremented and that you are not actually returning a Promise from `getMonthlyData` so you will return an empty result before queries are done.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent to your query with async errors fixed and as a single query should be:

```
async getMonthlyData(db, teamId) {
  return db('issues')
    .where({team_id: teamId})
    .whereBetween(db.raw(`EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_created::date)`), [1,6]);
}
```

Another way to write it with an additional column telling the extracted month would be:

```
async getMonthlyData(db, teamId) {
  // after this query you can easily group the resulted issues by month
  return db('issues')
    .select('*', db.raw(`EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_created::date) as month`))
    .where({team_id: teamId})
    .whereBetween(month, [1,6]);
}
```